# An open continuous image of a Baire space is a Baire space proof question

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ and $(Y,T_1)$ be topological spaces and $f: (X,T) \rightarrow (Y,T_1)$ be a continuous open mapping.  If $(X,T)$ is a Baire space, prove that $(Y,T_1)$ is a Baire space.

I start with:  Let $\{Y_n\}$ be a sequence of open dense subsets and $V \in T_1$ be arbitrary.
Since $f$ is an open mapping, we can let $f(\{X_n\})$ = $\{Y_n\}$.
Because $(X,T)$ is a Baire space, $U \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n \neq \emptyset$.
Since $f$ is continuous, we can let $U$ = $f^{-1}(V)$.
Then $f^{-1}(V) \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(Y_n) \neq \emptyset$.
This implies $f^{-1}(V \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n) \neq \emptyset$.

Which leads to $V \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n \neq \emptyset$.

Am I assuming something here that I shouldn't be?

Comment: You should demand that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you explain why?

Comment: Otherwise, $Y$ need not be Baire. You could have e.g. $f^{-1}(V) = \varnothing$. Consider $Y$ the disjoint union (topological sum) of $X$ and a non-Baire space, and $f$ the canonical inclusion of $X$ in $Y$.

Comment: So what would be a good way to think about proving this without demanding that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: You can't. If $f(X) \subsetneqq Y$, then $Y$ need not be Baire. Of course $f(X)$ is a Baire space, but $f \colon X \to f(X)$ is surjective.

Comment: So the statement:------------[    Let $(X,T)$ and $(Y,T_1)$ be topological spaces and $f: (X,T) \rightarrow (Y,T_1)$ be a continuous open mapping.  If $(X,T)$ is a Baire space, prove that $(Y,T_1)$ is a Baire space.    ]-----------------


Is false unless f is also surjective?

Comment: @Oliver: Yes: the statement in your title is true, but the result in the first paragraph of your question is not. The hypotheses guarantee only that $f[X]$ is a Baire subspace of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not quite complete as it stands.

As the comments show, we need to assume that $f$ is surjective, or switch to $f[X]$ as the codomain to force this (so prove $f[X]$ is Baire).

It's OK to start with open and dense subsets $Y_n$ of $Y$. We need to show that $\bigcap_n Y_n$ is dense in $Y$ and so that it intersects every non-empty open subset $V$ of $Y$, so picking such a $V$ is also fine.

Then you state that "since $f$ is an open mapping, we can let $f\{X_n\} = \{Y_n\}$" which is sloppy notation and unclear as well. You mean to define the $X_n$, so say:

Let $X_n = f^{-1}[Y_n]$ for all $n$. By surjectivity, $f[X_n] = Y_n$ for all $n$ and by continuity of $f$, all $X_n$ are open.

The openness of $f$ is used to show that $X_n$ is dense in $X$: suppose $O$ is open and non-empty in $X$ then $f[O]$ is open non-empty in $Y$, so $y \in f[O] \cap Y_n$ exists. Then any $x \in O$ with $f(x) = y$ is in $X_n = f^{-1}[Y_n]$ as well, so $O \cap X_n \neq \emptyset$, showing $X_n$ is dense.

Then you should interchange the next two lines of your proof. (You have to introduce $U$ first, before you use it.) So set $U = f^{-1}[V]$ which is open (continuity) and non-empty (surjectivity!). As $X$ is Baire, $U$ intersects the dense set $\bigcap_n X_n$, say in $x$, and then $f(x) \in f[U] = V$ and for every $n$, $x \in X_n$ so $f(x) \in f[X_n] = Y_n$. So $f(x) \in V \cap \bigcap_n Y_n$, and indeed $\bigcap_n Y_n$ is dense in $Y$ as required.